# How to move Vue template markup into a method?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am learning Vue, coming from React world. I am trying to extract DOM markup to de-clutter, but I don't know how.

I have this markup here that is about to get much worse when I add a minute select input beside it:

```
<select
    v-if="post_scheduleEnabled === true"
    v-model="post_buttonType"
    id="post_buttonType"
    class="some classes"
    @blur="touchField('post_buttonType')"
>
    <option value="0">12 AM</option>
    <option value="1">1 AM</option>
    <option value="2">2 AM</option>
    <option value="3">3 AM</option>
    <option value="4">4 AM</option>
    <option value="5">5 AM</option>
    <option value="6">6 AM</option>
    <option value="7">7 AM</option>
    <option value="8">8 AM</option>
    <option value="9">9 AM</option>
    <option value="10">10 AM</option>
    <option value="11">11 AM</option>
    <option value="12">12 AM</option>
    <option value="13">1 PM</option>
    <option value="14">2 PM</option>
    <option value="15">3 PM</option>
    <option value="16">4 PM</option>
    <option value="17">5 PM</option>
    <option value="18">6 PM</option>
    <option value="19">7 PM</option>
    <option value="20">8 PM</option>
    <option value="21">9 PM</option>
    <option value="22">10 PM</option>
    <option value="23">11 PM</option>
</select>
```

If I was writing React, I would do this:

```
renderOptions = () => {
    const hours = [
        0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12,
        13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23
    ]
    return hours.map(hour => (
        <option>{hour}</option>
    ))
}

...

<select>
    {this.renderOptions()}
</select>
```

What is the best way to do this in Vue?

Is there a way I can make a method and call it the same?

like:

```
<select>
    {{ renderOptions() }}
</select>
```

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-for In this regard Vue is like Angular.

Comment: Nice that works. If you make that into an answer, I'll mark it as correct. I was able to get it working by adding an instance method called `getHours()` and then I did `v-for="hour in getHours()"`.

Comment: By the way, you can use [JSX in Vue](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html)

Comment: I would love to see an example Lars. I read about that in the documentation before and heard from others, but I've never seen it used in standard situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue (like Angular) creates specific attributes ([*directives*](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Directives)) to let you manage such use case from the HTML markup itself. The idea is that all the markup is gathered in one place ("*separation of concerns*" as people say), whereas with React you have the freedom to split it among methods.

The typical way to address your case is using the [`v-for`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-for) directive and component [`data`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      optionValues: [0, 1, 2, 3],
    };
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>

<div id="app">
  <select>
    <option v-for="value in optionValues">{{value}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

But the source for `optionValues` can be also a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#computed), one of the [`props`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#props), the result of one of the [`methods`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#methods) (like you did in your comment), or even inline (and you can be helped with a [range](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Range)):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>

<div id="app">
  <select>
    <option v-for="value in [0, 1, 2, 3]">{{value}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```